# open dialog jquery ui with mvc.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

Hi everyone I am very new with jquery ui, I am try to create a Dialog when I click  a link, but my app open a white page.

this is my link

```
 <%: Html.ActionLink("Select Image", "SelectImage", "VacationPackage", null, new { @class = "newWindows" })%>
```

in the same view  I have this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#newWindows").dialog();
    });
</script>
```

my problem is I don't know how create my view I put this ...

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Administration.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    SelectImage
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>SelectImage</h2>

<% Html.RenderPartial("ListImage"); %> 

</asp:Content>
```

Buy don't open the ListImage.. only a white page.

What is the problem??? I am trying many examples but i obtain the same result. any idea???

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puh ;) many mistakes.

- your dialog should be a div container.
- your link should fire the `$("#<DIV_CONTAINER_ID").dialog();`

Something like this...

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("dialogOpener").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog()
        });
    });
    </script>

    <div id="dialog">Hello, iam a Dialog!</div>
    <a id="dialogOpener">Open Dialog</a>
```

Comment: thanks dknaack, but I have the same problem with the change, I don't know what is wrong. I think I show the view in a wrong place. I have a view, it is a form and there I have link to call the dialog. In the same view I have the javascript and the div to open de dialog. The link call to method SelectImage this open to partiaView like this return View("_SelectImage"); I think this is the problem ... the partialview is empty...and when a click it show me the white page, but i dont know how activate my dialog..if I call $(function (){ $("dialogOpener").click(function (){ $("#dialog").dialog()});